# PHP decrypting the encrypted sek using the appkey

Tags: php, encryption

I'm trying eInvoice API using PHP. I need to decrypting the encrypted sek using the appkey after I received authkey generation.
I'm having the following code

```
$key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
$AppKey = Encrypt($key, $bob_public_key);

var_dump(DecryptBySymmetricKey($sek, $key));

function Encrypt($appKey, $Publickey)
{
    openssl_public_encrypt($appKey, $encrypted, $Publickey);
    return base64_encode($encrypted);
}
function DecryptBySymmetricKey($encrypted_string, $encryption_key) {
    $cipher     = 'AES-256-CBC';
    $options    = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA;
    $hash_algo  = 'sha256';
    $sha2len    = 32;
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
    $iv = substr($encrypted_string, 0, $ivlen);
    $hmac = substr($encrypted_string, $ivlen, $sha2len);
    $ciphertext_raw = substr($encrypted_string, $ivlen+$sha2len);
    
    $original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext_raw, $cipher, $encryption_key, $options, $iv);
    
    $calcmac = hash_hmac($hash_algo, $ciphertext_raw, $encryption_key, true);
    
    if(function_exists('hash_equals')) {
        if (hash_equals($hmac, $calcmac)) return $original_plaintext;
    } else {
        if ($this->hash_equals_custom($hmac, $calcmac)) return $original_plaintext;
    }
}
```

But this didn't return the decrypting text. Always it returns NULL. Can you please any one help me on this.

Comment: This may be because "hash_equals" isn't defined and your classes function "hash_equals_custom" is returning a falsy. Can you also include the "hash_equals_custom" for more context?

Comment: I have tried this openssl_decrypt($sek, 'aes-128-cbc', $key) even this also didn't return anything.

Comment: Please post a link to the documentation of the eInvoice system in question, which contains implementation details (AppKey length, applied algorithm etc.) and which you used to implement the code.

Comment: I have referred this link of einvoice https://einv-apisandbox.nic.in/sample-code-in-c-sharp-dot-net.html, they have given c# and java code.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to decrypt the SEK with the AppKey, the Java code in the section [*Symmetric Key Decryption using Java*](https://einv-apisandbox.nic.in/sample-code-in-java.html), i.e. the method `decrptyBySyymetricKey()` is relevant (typos already in the documentation). This code is functionally different from the posted PHP code (e.g. regarding mode, MAC etc.). A PHP implementation functionally identical to the Java code is e.g.:

```php
<?php
function DecryptBySymmetricKey($encryptedSek, $appKey) {
    $sek = openssl_decrypt($encryptedSek, 'aes-256-ecb', $appKey, 0);
    return base64_encode($sek);
}

// Test
// $appKey = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32);
$appKey = hex2bin('b42b0df750c207f0288cced8d89976431c43247ba45b64bf3ef0ed9325f9fb16'); // test key for comparison with C# code
$encryptedSek = 'RwDmJm/OBNW8bVTISa7nmOuMiixp9blBM0g3S0v7h1OKZ9SMJGlg0DVpARRyLadH';
$decryptedSek = DecryptBySymmetricKey($encryptedSek, $appKey);
print($decryptedSek . PHP_EOL); // MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTIzNDU2Nzg5MDE=
?>
```

The following Java code returns the same result using `decrptyBySyymetricKey()`:

```java
byte[] appKey = Hex.decodeHex("b42b0df750c207f0288cced8d89976431c43247ba45b64bf3ef0ed9325f9fb16"); // test key for comparison with PHP code
String encryptedSek = "RwDmJm/OBNW8bVTISa7nmOuMiixp9blBM0g3S0v7h1OKZ9SMJGlg0DVpARRyLadH";
String decryptedSek = decrptyBySyymetricKey(encryptedSek, appKey);  
System.out.println(decryptedSek); // MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTIzNDU2Nzg5MDE=
```

Both implementations are thus functionally identical.

Please note that `decrptyBySyymetricKey()` applies the [*Apache Commons Codec*](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.15) for Base64 en-/decoding. `Hex.decodeHex()` is also from this library.

Also note that according to the documentation (see [*FAQs*](https://einv-apisandbox.nic.in/FaqsonAPI.html) on the eInvoice site) and consistent with AES-256 the AppKey must be a 32 bytes key while you are using a 16 bytes key, i.e. it must be:

```php
$appKey = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32);
```

However, if eInvoice also accepts 16 bytes key (which I don't know) and you want to use a 16 bytes key, then of course you need to apply `aes-128-ecb` (instead of `aes-256-ecb`) in your PHP code.

Comment: your answer helped me lot. Thanks a lot. I have completed this GST module work now.

Comment: I need one more help on decrypt the SignedInvoice. Could you please help me on this.

Comment: @VinothKumar - Please post a new question with all information needed to answer it.

Comment: Okay, This I have done by using   $parts   = explode('.', $encodeeI);
  $header   = $parts[0];
  $payload   = $parts[1]; 
  return base64_decode($header).base64_decode($payload); it's working fine now.